# SMTP proxy (relay) with SSL

Tags: ubuntu, smtp

#### Short question

I need some kind of SMTP proxy server which does not verify passwords and directly pass credentials and data to a target server. The target server uses self-signed certificate so I want use my own certificate.

It would be nice if the proxy could also connect to open SMTP server from ISP with credentials removed.

#### Problem description

There are email clients in a network which use same SMTP server with self a signed certificate. Once this server was blacklisted so clients could not send emails. I want some proxy which I can use to direct traffic to the final server and in case of blacklisting I could change target on one place to alternative open SMTP from ISP.

So I want use my certificate for clients to avoid setting the self-signed certificate as trusted every year but still accept this certificate.

I have tried postfix but I was not able to set it transparent. It tries to retry in case of error instead of report it to client.

Comment: I'm unclear why you want a proxy. SMTP is a store-and-forward oriented protocol. Why not just put up an MTA w/ whatever certificates you want installed and smart-host rules configured to forward the traffic where you want it to go?

Comment: I do not have static ip and isp is blocking port 25 except his own smtp server. So for me is solution using email provider's smtp server or isp's. And there is another reason. Because of external email provider I can't store and verify passwords for mail accounts.
But I am still looking for other solutions where smtp proxy will not be used.